# Is is possible to create an icon for web app?

Tags: iphone, web-applications

I am new to web apps. I read just about everyting of Apple's website about creating web apps for iphone but could not find any info on how do you create an icon that would be placed on user's phone that would launch the app.

I mean, is it possible to have an icon added to the iphone/ipad for a web app that would launch your web app the same was it launches the regular app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [Apple documentation on web apps](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/safariwebcontent/configuringwebapplications/configuringwebapplications.html),

Basicaly use:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="touch-icon-iphone.png" />
```

(put it in your `<head>`)

If you don't want the shiny effect added to your icon use:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="touch-icon-iphone.png" />
```